# VSCode + Typescript: IntelliSense doesn't work for css import

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have a project with Vite, React and Typescript. I am using VSCode as IDE.

Any file other than .ts or .tsx doesn't get VSCode IntelliSense working when I write `import './...'`

I first though it was an issue or a missing extension for VSCode but after adding `"allowJs": true` in my **tsconfig.json**, I could see .js, .cjs, etc..

Same with `"resolveJsonModule": true`, I get intellisense for JSON file import.

However, I don't get CSS/SCSS IntelliSense. Is there a way to turn on VSCode IntelliSense for more file extensions or allow typescript to import CSS/SCSS/SVG/etc..?

Answer (score 1):

A temporary fix I found is to write "import from './'". The .scss files are visible that way, but not if I write "import styles from './'". Same applies for .css. Then obviously add back in an alias if you require.

EDIT:

Fixed it by adding this to my vscode settings.json:

```
"javascript.suggest.paths": false,
"typescript.suggest.paths": false
```

I am also using Kohler's Intellisense extension.